# Why this MySQL UPDATE with sub-query is acting weird?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I think I'm losing it! :-/

So, I have this MySQL UPDATE query ...

```
UPDATE `Jobs`
SET `Archived` = 'Y'
WHERE `JobCode` IN (
    SELECT `JobCode` FROM (
        SELECT m.`JobCode`
        FROM `Jobs` as jx
        JOIN (
            SELECT j.`JobCode`, MAX(c.`CutDate`) AS MaxCutDate
            FROM `Cuts` AS c
            LEFT JOIN `Jobs` AS j ON (j.`JobCode`=c.`JobCode`)
            GROUP BY j.`JobCode`
        ) AS m ON (m.`JobCode`=jx.`JobCode`)
        WHERE m.MaxCutDate < '2014-01-01'
    ) AS tmp_table
)
```

The tables `Customers`, `Jobs` and `Cuts` are part of a simple relational group. `Customers` have multiple `Jobs`, `Jobs` have multiple `Cuts`. *I have left this complexity in for my question here, because I am not sure if it is part of the problem or not and didn't want to over simplify the problem away.*

The query's intention is to set `Jobs`.`Archived` to `'Y'` for all `Jobs`
that have not had a `Cut` record created since before `2014-01-01 OK`, according to the `Cuts`.`CutDate` field. Seemed simple enough at the time.

So, the problem is this; The following section of the query *correctly* produces a single column result, containing only `JobCode`'s that have no `Cut` records on file with a `Cut`.`CutDate` since `2014-01-01` ...

This works as intended ...

```
    SELECT `JobCode` FROM (
        SELECT m.`JobCode`
        FROM `Jobs` as jx
        JOIN (
            SELECT j.`JobCode`, MAX(c.`CutDate`) AS MaxCutDate
            FROM `Cuts` AS c
            LEFT JOIN `Jobs` AS j ON (j.`JobCode`=c.`JobCode`)
            GROUP BY j.`JobCode`
        ) AS m ON (m.`JobCode`=jx.`JobCode`)
        WHERE m.MaxCutDate < '2014-01-01'
    ) AS tmp_table
```

[ NOTE: The double SELECT ( SELECT ...))) is to get around an inane but well known issue with MySQL. I see no problem here. ]

As an example, the above might produce the following ...

```
JobCode
-------
  930
  935
  936
```

There happen to also be `JobCode`'s 931 through 934 in the `Jobs` table. These are *not* included in the above results, because they do not have `Cut` records with `CutDate`'s more recent than `2014-01-01`. This is what I want and what I expected.

**HOWEVER** ... when I run the full query, including the `UPDATE` part ...

```
UPDATE `Jobs`
SET `Archived` = 'Y'
WHERE `JobCode` IN (
    SELECT `JobCode` FROM (
        SELECT m.`JobCode`
        FROM `Jobs` as jx
        JOIN (
            SELECT j.`JobCode`, MAX(c.`CutDate`) AS MaxCutDate
            FROM `Cuts` AS c
            LEFT JOIN `Jobs` AS j ON (j.`JobCode`=c.`JobCode`)
            GROUP BY j.`JobCode`
        ) AS m ON (m.`JobCode`=jx.`JobCode`)
        WHERE m.MaxCutDate < '2014-01-01'
    ) AS tmp_table
)
```

... then well, crazy things seem to happen! What I *expect* is that ONLY `Jobs` records that exist in the output from the `SELECT` should get updated. But random other `Jobs` records do as well! I say, "random", because a) I can find no rhyme or reason for the ones they.

So, that's the problem. Please oh pretty, *pretty please* ... WTF am I missing here?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: can you try this: UPDATE `Jobs`
SET `Archived` = 'Y'
WHERE `JobCode` IN (
        SELECT m.`JobCode`
        FROM `Jobs` as jx
        JOIN (
            SELECT j.`JobCode`, MAX(c.`CutDate`) AS MaxCutDate
            FROM `Cuts` AS c
            LEFT JOIN `Jobs` AS j ON (j.`JobCode`=c.`JobCode`)
            GROUP BY j.`JobCode`
        ) AS m ON (m.`JobCode`=jx.`JobCode`)
        WHERE m.MaxCutDate < '2014-01-01'
)

Answer (score 1):

I think the order of your left join is incorrect. You want to include all JobCodes from the Jobs table and then if there are records in the Cuts table then you want to include them if they exist.

You also don't handle what happens when a cut record doesn't exist in that case the CutDate will be null.

```
    SELECT j.`JobCode`
      FROM `Jobs` as j
 LEFT JOIN `Cuts` AS c ON c.`JobCode` = j.`JobCode`
  GROUP BY j.`JobCode`
    HAVING MAX(IFNULL(c.`CutDate`, '2016-01-01')) < '2014-01-01'
```

So the date can be set to after 2014 or before depending on if you want to archive the record or not if not Cuts exist for the record. You can use having statements to work on aggregate functions inorder to use the max function and then compare if it is less than 2014.

I'm not sure why you were seeing random results, but I think between the left join being incorrect and maybe not aliasing the JOBS table in the update statement. I'd suggest testing it out before running the update with the following.

```
# ju will stand for "Jobs Update"
SELECT ju.`JobCode`
  FROM `Jobs` ju
 WHERE ju.`JobCode` IN (
        SELECT j.`JobCode`
          FROM `Jobs` as j
     LEFT JOIN `Cuts` AS c ON c.`JobCode` = j.`JobCode`
      GROUP BY j.`JobCode`
        HAVING MAX(IFNULL(c.`CutDate`, '2016-01-01')) < '2014-01-01'
 )
```

If you're ready to run the update then you can switch it over.

```
# ju will stand for "Jobs Update"
UPDATE `Jobs` ju
   SET ju.`Archived` = 'Y'
 WHERE ju.`JobCode` IN (
        SELECT j.`JobCode`
          FROM `Jobs` as j
     LEFT JOIN `Cuts` AS c ON c.`JobCode` = j.`JobCode`
      GROUP BY j.`JobCode`
        HAVING MAX(IFNULL(c.`CutDate`, '2016-01-01')) < '2014-01-01'
 )
```

Comment: Thanks. I get so confused about LEFT vs RIGHT vs just JOIN -- and I completely forgot about HAVING. I'm running tests now ...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `JOIN` instead of `WHERE` condition?

```sql
UPDATE `Jobs`
JOIN (SELECT `JobCode` FROM (
        SELECT m.`JobCode`
        FROM `Jobs` as jx
        JOIN (
            SELECT j.`JobCode`, MAX(c.`CutDate`) AS MaxCutDate
            FROM `Cuts` AS c
            JOIN `Jobs` AS j ON (j.`JobCode`=c.`JobCode`)
            GROUP BY j.`JobCode`
        ) AS m ON (m.`JobCode`=jx.`JobCode`)
        WHERE m.MaxCutDate < '2014-01-01'
    ) AS tmp_table
  ) AS t ON t.`JobCode` = `Jobs`.`JobCode`
SET `Archived` = 'Y'
```

Also I replaces `LEFT JOIN` in subquery with `JOIN`. Because we are selecting `JobCode` which must exists in table `Jobs` - this is necessary for `UPDATE`. If `JobCode` is null, then there are nothing to update as I understood.

Comment: I did originally try this type of JOIN. But I just couldn't get my head around the syntax (int he UPDATE context) or what exactly it would do. I'm running some tests now, to try and nail this concept down.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the great advice everyone. You were ALL correct.

In the end, the "random" results were in fact an error in the surrounding PHP code. Random Jobs were not in fact being archived.

On top of that, I'm using `phpMyAdmin`, which apparently has a (another :-P) bug. When I use sub-queries, it will report, "Zero (0) rows affected", when that's simply not true! I was believing this and not checking further on the actual table contents after my query. I wasted a LOT of time like this. :-/

Losing the LEFT in LEFT JOIN definitely helps with the case where a Job has no related Cuts record.

In the end, I went with @Andrew's version, only since I believe it would be the most efficient, due to not using HAVING ... that and it's the way I originally tried, so it feels better hehe ...

```
<!-- language: SQL -->
UPDATE `Jobs`
JOIN (SELECT `JobCode` FROM (
        SELECT m.`JobCode`
        FROM `Jobs` as jx
        JOIN (
            SELECT j.`JobCode`, MAX(c.`CutDate`) AS MaxCutDate
            FROM `Cuts` AS c
            JOIN `Jobs` AS j ON (j.`JobCode`=c.`JobCode`)
            GROUP BY j.`JobCode`
        ) AS m ON (m.`JobCode`=jx.`JobCode`)
        WHERE m.MaxCutDate < '2014-01-01'
    ) AS tmp_table
  ) AS t ON t.`JobCode` = `Jobs`.`JobCode`
SET `Archived` = 'Y'
```

Thanks again!